# Send email on multiple items selected

Tags: 2010, list-view, designer-workflow, email

I have very specific requirement. Before i explain, please note that i can not use server side object model. I have to complete the task using client side and Designer.

Below are the things which i need to achieve :
1.) Create a button(will prefer ribbon button) on the list view page which will get enabled on multiple items selection.
2.) When the button will be clicked an email has to be sent. the body of the email will contain details of the items which are selected.

I know this could be done with single item selection using Designer Workflow but as sharepoint does not support to start single workflow on multiple items, i am stuck.

Regards

Comment: the email will go to which user?

Comment: It will be sent to AD Group.

Answer (score 1):

Create another list which will store ItemIds (id's of the list item whose details needs to be in mail.This field can be  multi look up), and the user/group to whom the email needs to be sent and another column EmailBody(contains the details of the items selected).

Attach a workflow to this list which will send mail to the user/group with that EmailBody column data as body of email.Trigger this Workflow on item added.

You can follow this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407458%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for creating ribbon button.

On click on  this link open a modal dialog where the user can specify to whom mail needs to be send.Then on button click save it to a list with EmailBody containing the details of the items selected in html format, which will trigger email workflow.

Alternatively you can try another approach where on click of the ribbon button specify to 'ToEmailId' and then using javascript open an instance of outlook send email where the Toaddress , email body will be populated by javascript and the user will have to click the Send button.See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899476/how-to-add-html-in-a-email-body-using-javascript) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds like an option. I will try.